# Do I have to use the localized version of a directory?

Tags: macos, cocoa, directory, nsfilemanager

Suppose I want to save something to the `Pictures` directory.

I normally would get the path by doing this:

```
  NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSPicturesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

But now suppose the user is not using english. Is this approach OK for all languages or do I have to use the localized version by adding this line?

```
path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:path];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "display" name means exactly that-- the name "displayed", whether in Chinese or Urdu or SomeWackoEse...

Since you "want to save something", you are talking about your code, not what is displayed to the user-- what you are concerned with is the "actual" name of the directory, which is what you get from NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains().

You would not need displayNameAtPath() unless for example you want to echo the "displayed" name of the directory in a dialog or something, in the User's language.